# Unable to get the _NewEnum property of the PivotItems class - Looping on All PivotItems in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, performance, pivot-table

I have a worksheet which contains pivot tables - I want to add a button that will entirely expand, or collapse, every field, on every table, for this sheet.

You can see the code in it's current form below, as well as the test document that I am running it against.  I have two issues:

- The code runs very slowly, in some cases more slowly than doing it by hand.  Is there a more efficient way to set the "showdetail" property of all pivot items?  I have searched here, MSDN, etc., but not found any snippets doing what I need.
- The code works fine on the smaller Src B/C/D examples, but fails on Src A, with the error "Unable to get the _NewEnum property of the PivotItems class".  I'm able to find a few hits on "Unable to get xyz property of the PivotItems class", but none for _NewEnum, and none of the proposed solutions seem to be working for me. What's going on here?  "NewEnum property" makes me think its trying to operate on a PivotItem value from the list, but the item isn't there, but how could that be? I'm not specifying a value, only saying "operate on each item you find".

Test File: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TKMc2C0qgKWzb7veIZbOPlOqbJtZfjo9)

Code:

```
Option Explicit

'  expand all fields on all pivot tables
Sub expandPivots()

On Error GoTo errorTrap

'  generic code to speed up vba
With Application
  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  .DisplayAlerts = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim targetField As PivotField
Dim targetItem  As PivotItem
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetTable As PivotTable


'  only want to run on the active sheet
Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet

'  loop through all pivots
For Each targetTable In targetSheet.PivotTables

  '  make sure table is fully up to date before operating on it
  targetTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
  targetTable.RefreshTable

  '  turn off table updates before looping through the rest
  targetTable.ManualUpdate = True

For Each targetField In targetTable.PivotFields
For Each targetItem In targetField.PivotItems

  targetItem.ShowDetail = True

Next targetItem
Next targetField

'  turn updates back on for the table
  targetTable.ManualUpdate = False
Next targetTable

'  turn everything else back on
With Application
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  .DisplayAlerts = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Exit Sub
errorTrap:

'  turn everything else back on, even in failure
With Application
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  .DisplayAlerts = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox "Error Desc: " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Assert targetField.PivotItems.Count > 0` before entering the inner `For Each` loop (it's weird anyway - an object collection without items should just jump the loop).

Comment: Loop over each RowItem and ColumnItem instead of all PivotItems to omit filter items (PageItem) and values (DataItem).